# Не открывая VisualStudio выходит ошибка необработанное исключение system.io.filenotfoundexception

Tags: visual-studio, файловая-система, windows-7, jit

При включении ПК (или при закрытии студии) появляется ошибка "необработанное исключение system.io.filenotfoundexception произошло в "[1792(тут обычно разные цифры)]AddInUtil.exe"". Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая у вас Windows?

Comment: Windows 7, сделал стиль рабочего стола классическим.

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит подумать над обновлением. Win7 уже давно не поддерживается, так с чего бы 2019 студии беспокоиться о работоспособности на такой старой версии? Видимо что-то там где-то захардкожено внутри студии и этот путь попросту отсутствует в Win7. В любом случае можете установить старую VS, какую-нибудь 2008

Comment: Вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements) написано про Win7, надо пакет обновлений установить

Comment: Я пока до 15 числа не хочу трогать винду, так как диплом. У меня эта ошибка не происходила до момента, когда я не сделал приложение с выводом данных на блокнот, есть возможность, что в этом дело?

Comment: Есть, какую версию .net вы используете? .net core, .net framework? .net framework - под винду, там вызываются виндовские штуки для работы с файловой системой и прочей фигней, так что стоит перенести на какую-нибудь наиболее новую версию которая поддерживается win7

Comment: @Aarnihauta, у меня обновления, зачастую не устанавливаются, они просто бесконечно грузятся и всё, но постараюсь скачать, если получится

Comment: @Aarnihauta, .net framework

Comment: А какая версия? Я бы посоветовал .net framework 4.0 и ниже т.к он поддерживается win7, там не нужно устанавливать обнову sp1

Comment: @Aarnihauta, если версия visual, то 2019, а если версия framework'а я не знаю как узнать, если нужна версия framwork'a можете подсказать, как узнать?

Comment: Project -> Properties -> (Application -> General) -> поле Target Framework

Comment: @Aarnihauta, У меня версия Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @Aarnihauta, я проверил wind'у, у меня уже пакет обновлений SP1 установлен

Comment: Отлично, тогда перейдем к сути вопроса. У вас не открывается Visual Studio? или не записывается в файл?

Comment: @Aarnihauta, по факту всё работает, но это ошибка выводится, когда только запустил комп, или только, иногда, когда закрываю visual studio

Comment: Думаю Вам стоит подождать пару часов более опытных пользователей сайта. Тут явно вина не C#, тут скорее даже системное администрирование, так что стоит изменить теги

Comment: Запостите этот вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта, там больше шансов что заметят